# How to expand all item in a TreeSelect from Sakai PrimeVUE?

Tags: vue.js, primevue, sakai, vue-treeselect

I'm using [TreeSelect](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/treeselect) from [Sakai PrimeVUE template](https://www.primefaces.org/sakai-vue), I would like to keep all items expanded on open the component, but could not find this option in the documentation.

My `TreeSelect` implementation:

```
<TreeSelect v-model="product.category" :overlayVisible="true" selectionMode="single"  :options="categories" @change="categoryChange(product)"></TreeSelect>
```

Info from my package.json:

```
"primevue": "^3.11.0",
"vue": "3.2.9",
```

Answer (score 2):

`TreeSelect` has a method named [`expandPath(path)`](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/089f315/src/components/treeselect/TreeSelect.vue#L352-L358), where `path` is the `key` property in a tree node.

To expand all nodes, collect all the keys from the tree nodes, and then pass each of them to `expandPath()`:

1. Add a template ref on `<TreeSelect>` to use it later in script:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const treeRef = ref()
const treeNodes = ref()
</script>

<template>
  <TreeSelect ref="treeRef" :nodes="treeNodes" ⋯ />
</template>
```

2. Create a method (e.g., named `getKeysFromTree`) to extract the keys from an array of tree nodes:

```js
const getKeysFromNode = (node) => {
  const keys = [node.key]
  if (node.children) {
    keys.push(...node.children.flatMap(getKeysFromNode))
  }
  return keys
}

const getKeysFromTree = (tree) => tree.flatMap(getKeysFromNode)
```

3. In an `onMounted()` hook, use the template ref to call `expandPath()` on each of the tree's keys (extracted with `getKeysFromTree()` defined above):

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  const data = /* tree nodes data */
  treeNodes.value = data
  getKeysFromTree(data).forEach((key) => treeRef.value.expandPath(key))
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/expand-all-nodes-in-primevue-treeselect-kjsee3?file=/src/TreeSelectDemo.vue)